# How to add custom user name for EC2 AMI for connect to instance page in AWS UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I created an AMI using AWS Linux 2, which uses ec2-user as the default user for ssh.

When I directly spin up an EC2 machine. It shows

> ssh -i "abcd.pem" ec2-user@ec2-22.22.22.22.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

but when I create an AMI. Then It shows

> ssh -i "abcd.pem" root@ec2-22.22.22.22.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

same shown in the imge below

[image: Image showing AWS UI Connect to instance | SSH Client]

I want somehow to make it ec2-user instead of root in the UI.

Is there any way through which I can configure what should be the username shown in the AWS UI?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it ec2-user"? Since the AMI is a copy of the disk, it will still be configured to allow login via `ec2-user`. It is probably showing `root` because the AMI is not one provided directly by AWS, so simply ignore what it is saying and continue connecting the way you did before.

Comment: 1. by "make it ec2-user", I mean If there is a way from which I can tell the default username for the AMI.
2. I just created the Image of an already spined-up EC2 instance of AL2 by clicking the 'create image' option in AWS UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username shown on the SSH client tab is just a non modifiable placeholder.
Users and permissions on EC2 are managed at OS-level, where the standard AMIs have a different default user, as stated on the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html#ami-default-user-names).

There's no way to change that page.